# Slide down menu doesn't animate

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, css-transitions, nav

Right now I'm trying to get my drop down navigation list to animate. I can get it to fade, but it absolutely WILL NOT slide.

Here's a sample of the drop down.

```
<div id="nav" class="navv">
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.domain.com">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Archives</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://domain.com/index.php?f=BackIssues&page=_Directory2012">Back Issues 2012</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://domain.com/index.php?f=BackIssues&page=_Directory2011">Back Issues 2011</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://domain.com/index.php?f=musicianfeatures&page=_MusicianFeatureDirectory">Musician Features</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://domain.com/index.php?f=cdreview&page=_cdReviewDirectory">CD Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://domain.com/index.php?f=artist&page=_ArtistFeatureDirectory">Visual Artist Features</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Coming Soon: Restaurant Reviews</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Calendars</a>
        <ul>
        <!--<li><a href="http://domain.com/index.php?f=calendar&page=TRF">TRF 44</a><li>-->
            <li><a href="http://domain.com/index.php?f=calendar&page=Music">Music &amp; Comedy</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://domain.com/index.php?f=calendar&page=OTR">On the Road Concert Calendar</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://domain.com/index.php?f=calendar&page=RoadTripz">Road Tripz</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://domain.com/index.php?f=calendar&page=Karaoke">Karaoke &amp; DJs</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://domain.com/index.php?f=calendar&page=Movies">Movie Times</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://domain.com/index.php?f=calendar&page=ToDo">Things to Do (Events)</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://domain.com/index.php?f=calendar&page=Stage">Stage &amp; Dance</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://domain.com/index.php?f=calendar&page=Art">Art &amp; Artifacts</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://domain.com/index.php?f=calendar&page=Subcal">Submit Calendar Item</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="http://domain.com/index.php?f=calendar&page=domain">domain</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Feedback/Subcal.html">Submit Calendar Item</a></li>-->
        </ul>
    </li>
```

And the CSS here:

```
    #navcon {
background:#7E2217;
width:979px;
border:2px solid #ffe680;
}

#nav {
width:983px;
height:44px;
position:relative;
z-index:200;
color:#ffe680;
font-family:Arial, Tahoma, san-serif;
font-size:1em;
margin:0 auto;
}

#nav ul {
list-style-type:none;
}

#nav ul li {
float:left;
position:relative;
z-index:200;
width:163px;
}

#nav ul li a {
border:1px solid #ffe680;
display:block;
text-align:left;
text-decoration:none;
color:#ffe680;
z-index:200;
-webkit-transition:background .09s ease-in;
-o-transition:background .09s ease-in;
-moz-transition:background .09s ease-in;
padding:12px;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
background:#E8A317;
color:#ffe680;
}

#nav ul li ul {
height:0;
overflow:hidden;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul {
height:auto;
overflow:shown;
position:absolute;
-webkit-transition:height 2s;
-o-transition:height 2s;
-moz-transition:height 2s;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul li a {
background:#fff;
color:#e8a317;
display:block;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
background:#e8a317;
color:red;
}
```

I've tried transitions for just height, nothing happens. Can I not use two transitioning elements? Because if I try one line for background and one for height nothing happens, also.

How can I get this navigation list to animate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss the <kbd>></kbd> after the <kbd>:hover</kbd> statement...

Try this:

```
/* set the hidden menu */
#nav ul li ul{top:-100px;position:absolute;opacity:0}
/* do the magic */
#nav ul li:hover > ul{top:44px;opacity:1}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Dvveq/

Cheers and good luck with your proyect!

Comment: Hmm... That works, but even on the fiddle example the menu comes down if you hover way below the actual menu.

Comment: I just give you the way and point you in the right direction... Now, you should do it! and adjust as your needs XD

Comment: Oh yeah I get that, I was just saying that the example is kind of useless lol. I've been at work but I've got it all working now. I didn't realize I should use positioning and opacity instead of height and overflows. Thanks!

Comment: I still don't know what the < after hover does though. I didn't use it because I didn't need it.

Comment: The > indicates 'children' so when you are on ul:hover, you are saying that the children li (> li) must have this new style. [take a look here, http://www.princexml.com/doc/8.1/selectors/] Cheers!

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. It works fine without it... But I'll use it and read up some more. Thanks for the help!!